# How to render image with background image and text on it?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, render

I'm developing an App where users can write and upload background image/color. So when they share it on social media I want to create an image on serverside with background color/image and text(custom fonts) on it.

I want to render image something similar to following screenshot of my app.
[image]

Any library or any other solution to render dynamic image on server side.

Comment: but can't you just use relativelayout with text?

Comment: @brykneval I'm using relative layout in android and it's working. When the user shares that post on web which requires rendering image for that post.

Comment: you can capture image pragmatically from your layout. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190897/3758024

Comment: @gopal_patil This solution may work but I want to create an image when a user posts new post.  Also, I want to add app logo watermark and writers credit at bottom of image.

Comment: you can add logo and credits too on image, you just need to create xml layout template with your required placements of view, pass the data to template when user tap on share, capture entire view when data rendered.

Comment: Let me try. is image size depend on device size?

Comment: If we give fix width and height in px then I think it should work. let me try.

Comment: If you want to render text on an image using server side Java, I recommend reading the [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) and [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) in the Java2D tutorial.